# Can you compile PHP into a "binary" for distribution?

Tags: php, compilation, bytecode

I have some PHP code.  I want to share this code with people to run on their own servers, HOWEVER, I don't want them to have the source because I don't want to make it easy to modify, and I don't want to make it easy to tweak.  Is there any way to "compile" the PHP to bytecode, and then give people that to put on their servers in place of the php files?

To make it clearer: We have a server that hosts user generated content.  We want to make a "server package" available to people so that they can host their own content farms without moderation or with whatever rules they want to impose.  If we give them the raw PHP, it'll be easy for even a casual computer user to backwards engineer our system and hack our main server.  We want to just make it possible for some of our more dedicated users to host content that we would filter because everything we host officially has to be child appropriate, while at the same time not making it easy for troublesome persons to make their "first kill" by taking down a small team's server.

(Yes, I know a dedicated hacker can reverse engineer the opcode, but we're not big enough to attract true monsters or governments.  We just want to remove the temptation for script kiddies to try to tamper).

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: You could obfuscate it. For example: https://www.gaijin.at/en/tools/php-obfuscator

Comment: Yes, the key word here is "obfuscation". There have been many tools that claim to do this to varying degrees over the years, and listing the current ones would be off-topic here. Note that a compiler for any language is at best an *accidental* obfuscator, and some will do their best to *minimise* obfuscation, to make it easier to debug the compiled code.

Comment: Even I can puzzle out some obfuscated code with effort... what I was really looking for was something that literally could turn PHP into binaries, like how in the old days they used to put executables into /CGI-BIN and redirect to those.  Nothing exists?  (We do have the worst-case option to rewrite all this into C++ and run it like that... but it would be so very much easier and faster if we could just compile-up the PHP and have it run exactly like it does now, except no exposed source)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something that deters amateurs, you could try archiving the code into a [PHAR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php).